# NAT with TUN interface on vm

Tags: networking, iptables, virtualbox, nat

I'm trying to share a TUN connection from a virtualbox vm with the host machine and the wider local net. I have a android tethering program (easytether) that creates a TUN interface on a debian vm. I have tried using iptables nat to route packets from a (virtual) ethernet interface (eth1) on the vm. When making a http request using eth1 it returns 'no route to host'.

I set up iptables nat using:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -m state --state 
ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

(ill modify firewall later, just trying to get it to work)

packet forwarding is allowed, eth1 has a static ip, tun0 seems to have a static ip of 192.168.117.0 set by easytether. I've tried many, many different configurations of this same idea, using different dhcp servers, using different ip routes and interface settings, but now I feel like I'm shooting in the dark.

Any help as to why packets may not be forwarded to tun0 would be really appreciated! I'm new to networking

Beyond this I am trying to use a bridged interface between the host pc and eth1 and trying to have all the hosts internet traffic directed towards the bridge, then on to tun0

Comment: two comments: since it's a VM, the host too must have a correct setting. A problem can come from host's routing (or bridging) as well as the VM. 2nd: allowing a possible path for packets with iptables will not change its route: if the packet is not going through tun0, allowing it to go through tun0 won't change the routing decision. You have to state routing informations in the question: `ip -br link; ip -br -4 address; ip -4 route; ip -4 rule`